# I Can't Log In to my Account after Password reset

Tags: data-recovery, ecryptfs, recovery-mode, password-recovery, passwd

I forgot the password to my admin account in ubuntu, I googled how to reset ubuntu admin password, then did the following steps from the tutorial that I found online

Enter Recovery

Drop to root shell

mount -o remount,rw /

passwd username

Enter new UNIX password

Retype new UNIX password

It said password updated successfully.

Now when I try to log in the password gets accepted but I get returned back to log in screen. But when I opened terminal from log in screen using CTRL + ALT + F1 I was able to log in to my account from terminal with the new password, I can see there are two files there named 'Access Your private Data.desktop' & 'Readme.txt' What does this mean?

Now, I had the old password written down, but it is was at my home, and I was in another city, thats why I decided to reset but now I am locked out after entering password it just bounces back to Log In Screen.

Now I am back home I have my old password in my hands, what do I do now? I really need access to my HOME directory so I can take a backup of some important files.

Would changing the password back to the original old password using RECOVERY PASSWD work? I don't have a back up of HOME, How do I take a backup of encrypted HOME before attempting to change the password back to the old one? I'm in a bit of a panic, and am worried I'm going to screw things up more.I am really new to ubuntu, only been using it for the past 7 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[information you missed when you skipped was - LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJjit.jpg) I am going to guess that changing your password gets you through the login, tries to access home and cannot, changing back to original password may actually work. And I would think safe to try. Did the encrypted home have its own pass phrase, that you took note of. If you wanted to you could make a backup of the home (but still encrypted) and if home is on its own partition using dd or pv

dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdx of=/y/home.img status=progress oflag=sync

replacing x & y with your values.

Comment: Yes the new password gets accepted but it just goes back to log in screen. Should I change it back to old passwprd?

Comment: logic tells me you changed it once, so changing again back to old password should be ok.

Comment: once you are in I would create a 2nd user account, this maybe useful. Even if you do not get in can you create a 2nd user from recovery shell.

Comment: I tested the use of using  /nonexistent as a home path for login - This does not work, the directory has to exist. So with the 2nd user you would need something like a /home2/user

Comment: So I took the leap of faith & changed the password back to the old one, it worked!!!!! I guess from now on I won't impulsively follow any tutorial I find online without first checking it with people here first. I had forgotten that I had checked the option to encrypt HOME when I installed ubuntu & the tutorial did not mention anything about that. Thanks Keith.

Comment: now do a backup & read up on encrypted home

Comment: if you skipped define the encrypted home passphrase when installing  - make one by - 

ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase - You can change the passphrase with this ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase - unless you did not skip & recorded it

Comment: Access Your private Data.desktop' & 'Readme.txt' What does this mean? It telling you that you can access the encrypted data file but not the data inside. The readme may explain this.

Comment: If you wanted to make a quick backup you could copy this file to a new location & use the pass-phrase to access it. I leave you to experiment with that one.

Comment: To my answer I added an image link. Do you remember seeing this when you installed ?

Comment: Yes I did see that when I installed ubuntu.

Comment: so did you record the pass-phrase ? or skipped it - I would strongly recommend making a pass-phrase using my above instructions.

Comment: Just made the pass-phrase using you instructions, I have also taken a additional backup of the pass-phrase & stored it on a memory card & a USB Flash Drive just in case. Thanks Keith.